# Merge two tables into one table in sql server

Tags: c#, sql, json, sql-server, database-schema

I have these schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Ndc
(
    [NdcId] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), 
    [Code] VARCHAR(256) NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE [RxCui]
(
    [RxCuiId] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), 
    [Code] VARCHAR(256) NULL, 
)

CREATE TABLE [RxCuiNdc]
(
    [RxCuiNdcId] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), 
    [RxCuiId] INT NOT NULL, 
    [NdcId] INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_RxCuiNdc_Ndc] FOREIGN KEY (NdcId) REFERENCES Common.Ndc(NdcId), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_RxCuiNdc_RxCui] FOREIGN KEY (RxCuiId) REFERENCES Common.RxCui(RxCuiId), 
)
```

I have a JSON which is a list of drug labels and each label is associated with two array of strings. One array would represent a list of RxCui and the other one would represent a list of Ndc. I would take the JSON file and insert every RxCui to the RxCui table and every Ndc in the Ndc table from the schema above. Assuming the tables have all of the Ndc and RxCui and there aren't any duplicates, then I want to map these to the RxCuiNdc table.

This is the class that represents the JSON

```
public class DrugLabel
    {
        public OpenFda openfda { get; set; }
    }

public class OpenFda
    {
        public IList<string> product_ndc { get; set; } = new List<string>();
        public IList<string> rxcui { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    }

public class DrugLabels
    {
        public List<DrugLabel> results { get; set; } = new List<DrugLabel>();
    }
```

I made an attempt at a stored procedure to create the mappings between the RxCui and Ndc.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MapRxCuiToNdc
    @rxCuiList varchar(MAX),
    @ndcList varchar(MAX)
AS
    DECLARE @rxCuiTable TABLE (RxCuiCode varchar(max)) 

    -- Insert statement
    INSERT INTO @rxCuiTable
    SELECT Value
    FROM  string_split(@rxCuiList, ',')  

    DECLARE @ndcTable TABLE (NdcCode varchar(max)) 

    -- Insert statement
    INSERT INTO @ndcTable
    SELECT Value
    FROM  string_split(@ndcList, ',')  

    MERGE INTO [Common].[RxCuiNdc] T
       USING (SELECT A.RxCuiId, A.Code AS RxCuiCode, B.NdcId, B.Code AS NdcCode
                FROM Common.RxCui A cross join Common.Ndc B
                WHERE A.Code IN (SELECT RxCuiCode FROM @rxCuiTable) AND B.Code IN (SELECT NdcCode FROM @ndcTable )
            ) S
          ON T.RxCuiId = S.RxCuiId AND T.NdcId = S.NdcId
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
       UPDATE
          SET T.NdcId = S.NdcId, T.RxCuiId = S.RxCuiId
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
       INSERT ( NdcId, RxCuiId ) VALUES ( S.NdcId, S.RxCuiId);
```

The problem I'm having is getting the right mappings. In my C# code im trying to find a way to send a list of every RxCui and Ndc without having to do a foreach on every label.

What I have so far is this

```
var data = new DrugLabels();
var productsNdc = data.results.Where(x => x.openfda?.product_ndc?.Count > 0).SelectMany(x => x.openfda.product_ndc).ToArray();
var rxCui = data.results.Where(x => x.openfda?.rxcui?.Count > 0).SelectMany(x => x.openfda.rxcui).ToArray();
await MedicationSearchStoredProcedure(string.Join(",", rxCui), string.Join(",", productsNdc));
```

The previous code would just have the stored procedure map every rxCui with every Ndc that I send. What I want is to map them according to the label, which the only way I can think of doing it is with a foreach, something like this.

```
foreach(var label in data.results)
{
    await MedicationSearchStoredProcedure(string.Join(",", label.openfda.rxcui), string.Join(",", label.openfda.product_ndc));
}
```

But that's what I don't want to have to do.

Any suggestions? Is the foreach the only way?

Comment: "In my C# code im trying to find a way to send a list of every RxCui and Ndc without having to do a foreach on every label."

Why?  I wouldn't use a stored procedure for this at all; I'd just insert the rows directly from C# code.  You can package them up in transactions if you're worried about data consistency or network efficiency.

Comment: When you mean send I assume you are doing either an INSERT query or or an UPDATE query.  Any time you store data into a database you need to specify the WHERE.  The WHERE need to be either a single row of the database or multiple rows of the database.  If you leave out the WHERE every row of the database will be updated with the same value.  So you need to have a loop  so each new item has a unique WHERE to specify the row.  The other choice is to create a STORED PROCEDURE which does the looping.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you get a single array of your results, then make the call.

```
List<string> rxcui = new List<string>();
List<string> product_ndc = new List<string>();

foreach(var label in data.results)
{
    rxcui.AddRange(string.Join(",", label.openfda.rxcui));
    product_ndc.AddRange(string.Join(",", label.openfda.product_ndc));
}

await MedicationSearchStoredProcedure(rxcui, product_ndc);
```